# Mirth String Handling

Tags: mirth

I'm using the code below to try and strip the file extension off the incoming file and replace it with "ACK";

Can't use .lastIndexOf as it's not available in Rhino.

```
var _filename       = String(sourceMap.get('originalFilename'));
pos = -1;
var search = ".";

for(var i = 0; i < _filename.length - search.length; i++) {
    if (_filename.substr(i, search.length) == search) {
        pos = i;
    }
}
logger.info('_pos:' + _pos);
```

Every time I get a pos value of -1
i.e.  Last full stop position not found.

BUT if I hardcode the filename in as "2020049.259317052.HC.P.F3M147-G" it works perfectly.

Is it something to do with the sourceMap.get('originalFilename') supplying a non-string or different 
character set ?

Comment: lastIndexOf is available in Rhino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

1. After reviewing and testing what agermano said he is correct.
2. In your sample code you are setting `pos = i` but logging `_pos`
3. New answer `var newFilename = _filename.slice(0, _filename.lastIndexOf('.'))`

## Older Answer

First, you are mixing JavaScript types and Java types.

```
var _filename       = String(sourceMap.get('originalFilename'));
```

Instead, do

```
var _filename       = '' + sourceMap.get('originalFilename');
```

This will cause a type conversion from Java String to JS string.

Secondly, there is an easier way to do what you are trying to do.

```
var _filenameArr = ('' + sourceMap.get('originalFilename')).split('.');
_filenameArr.pop()                     // throw away last item
var _filename = _filenameArr.join('.') // rejoin the array with out the last item

logger.info('_filename:' + _filename)
```

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you for the fix & advice.

One last question - is there a Rhino Javascript reference guide available ?
It's difficult to know what will work in Mirth JS & what won't.

Comment: Sort of... https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html Not sure how useful you will find it. These days I use a companion NodeApp with Mirth and just have Mirth make an HTTP call to the NodeApp to do anything beyond basic HL7 mapping.

Comment: Again, thank-you.
Seems like Mirth is a great software tool somewhat let down by its javascript.

Comment: Solution works, but the advice is only partially correct. `String(stringVar)` and `'' + stringVar` Both result in a javascript string.

Answer (score 2):

This was tested on mirth 3.5. Rhino does, in fact, have `String.prototype.lastIndexOf` for all mirth versions going back to at least mirth 3.0. You were correctly converting the java string from the sourceMap to a javascript string, however, it is not necessary in this case.

Java strings share String.prototype methods as long as there is not a conflict in method name. Java strings themselves have a lastIndexOf method, so that is the one being called in my answer. The java string is able to then borrow the slice method from javascript seamlessly. The javascript method returns a javascript string.

If for some reason the filename starts with a `.` and doesn't contain any others, this won't leave you with a blank filename.

```
var filename = $('originalFilename');
var index = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
if (index > 0) filename = filename.slice(0, index);
logger.info('filename: ' + filename);
```

That being said, I'm not sure why your original code wasn't working. When I replaced the first line with

```
var originalFilename = new java.lang.String('2020049.259317052.HC.P.F3M147-G');
var _filename       = String(originalFilename);
```

It gave me the correct pos value of 22.